# Combining "Do" and NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics

I have following code:

Two differential equations,each one of them with varying initial conditions

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol1[l0_] :=  NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[l0] == 2}, r, {x, 0,1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];

sol2[l0_] := NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == (r[x] /. First@sol1[l0]), n[l0] == 2}, n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
```

Next I try to plot the solution of the sum of solutions of differential equations as function of $l0$, but this doesn't work:

```
len = 3; sum := 0;
sump[l0_, i_] := n[i] /. sol2[l0];
Do[sum += sump[l0, i] , {i, len}];
Plot[sum, {l0, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

**Some alternative solution:**
If I choose "l0" in the first differential equation it works

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol1 := NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[2] == 2}, r, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
sol3[l0_] := NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == (r[x] /. First@sol1), n[l0] == 2},n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];

 len = 3;
 sump[l0_, i_] := n[i] /. sol3[l0];
 sum := 0;      
 Do[sum += sump[l0, i] , {i, len}];
 Plot[sum, {l0, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: Have you tried evaluating `sump[l0, 1]`, for instance? Do you notice the problem? If you do not provide a numerical value for `l0`, NDSolve cannot proceed symbolically and throws (many, many) errors.

Comment: You are right, sorry didn't I see it before. There is some way to plot the sum of some "n[1]/.sol[l0]+n2]/.sol[l0]+...n[5]/.sol[l0]" for different values of l0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all your equations are solvable analytically:

```
sol1 = DSolveValue[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[2] == 2}, r[x], x];
sol3 = DSolveValue[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == sol1, n[l0] == 2}, n[x], x];
sum = Total[sol3 /. {x -> {1, 2, 3}}];
Plot[sum, {l0, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I always try to put the simplest equations that I find in order to don't post my homework.

Comment: @Cruz Yes, I figure that this might be a toy example. Look at `ParametricNDSolve` though: that allows you to work with a numerical solution of a differential equation that contains a parameter. You can then substitute numerical values of the parameter and carry out the calculations on multiple values when you need to.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of @MarcoB was really helpful.

This is my propose of solution:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol1[l0_] :=  NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[l0] == 2}, r, {x, 0,1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];

sol2[l0_] := NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == (r[x] /. First@sol1[l0]), n[l0] == 2}, n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];



len = 3;

Plot[Sum[n[i] /. sol2[l0], {i, 1, len}], {l0, 1, 2}]
```

Sorry for posting this question, it was my confusion.